# DocumentClient not working after deploying to Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-cosmosdb

I am working on a POC (in .Net Core) to write some data to local Cosmos DB emulator using Azure DocumentClient.

```
private string _endpointUri = String.Empty;
private string _primaryKey = String.Empty;
private DocumentClient _client;
private string _databaseName = String.Empty;
private string _collectionName = String.Empty;

public CosmosDBStorage(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _endpointUri = configuration["CosmosDBEndpointUri"];
    _primaryKey = configuration["CosmosDBPrimaryKey"];
    _client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(_endpointUri), _primaryKey);
    _databaseName = configuration["CosmosDBName"];
    _collectionName = configuration["CosmosDBCollectionName"];
}

public async Task WriteAsync(dynamic data)
{
    try
    {
        await this._client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseName, _collectionName), data);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

It works fine in my local, however, after deploying the app to Azure I am trying use the same local Cosmos DB emulator for testing. It fails with below error.

**Exception message:**
An error occurred while sending the request

**Exception stack trace:**

```
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.HttpRequestMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.GatewayServiceConfigurationReader.<GetDatabaseAccountAsync>d__43.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Routing.GlobalEndpointManager.<GetDatabaseAccountFromAnyLocationsAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.GatewayServiceConfigurationReader.<InitializeReaderAsync>d__45.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.<InitializeGatewayConfigurationReader>d__319.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.<GetInitializationTask>d__85.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.<EnsureValidClientAsync>d__135.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.<GetCollectionCacheAsync>d__70.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.<CreateDocumentInlineAsync>d__143.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid1T0
at BotFrameworkDev.Storage.CosmosDBStorage.<WriteAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\GIS\ChatBot\BotFrameworkDev\BotFrameworkDev\Storage\CosmosDBStorage.cs:line 42
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at BotFrameworkDev.EchoBot.<OnTurn>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\GIS\ChatBot\BotFrameworkDev\BotFrameworkDev\EchoBot.cs:line 99
```

Any idea what could be the issue?

**Update:**

Added inner exception details.

**Exception message:** A connection with the server could not be established

**Exception stack trace:**

```
at BotFrameworkDev.Storage.CosmosDBStorage.<WriteAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\GIS\ChatBot\BotFrameworkDev\BotFrameworkDev\Storage\CosmosDBStorage.cs:line 42
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at BotFrameworkDev.EchoBot.<OnTurn>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\GIS\ChatBot\BotFrameworkDev\BotFrameworkDev\EchoBot.cs:line 99
```

Comment: Can you ensure that those configuration properties are properly set for production? Are they both in your `appsettings.development.json` and your `appsettings.json`?

Comment: @NickChapsas Yes, I have verified them. The settings look fine.

Comment: Can you check if there is an inner exception in your exception and throw that instead? You are currently showing a generic task exception which doesn't really help

Comment: @NickChapsas Thanks. I have updated it with the inner exception details. Please check.

Comment: Can you please verify that you can access this database with the credentials provided via https://cosmos.azure.com/ ? It is Azure's official data explorer. It will just prove that the credentials are correct and the database is accessible. Also try creating a document from that link to ensure that the key is a read/write key

Comment: I think problem with config settings or the location on CosmosDBStorage

Comment: @NickChapsas It says invalid connection string. Primary connection string for my emulator is `AccountEndpoint=https://localhost:8083/;AccountKey=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==`. I think, may be localhost does not work from Azure..

Comment: could u plz add both of your `appsettings.development.json`  and `appsettings.json`?

Comment: @ershoaib The problem is not with the appsettings I guess, as I can read the other app setting values from the same config.

Comment: Please refer to the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/cosmosdb-resource-uri-syntax-for-rest

Comment: @SouvikGhosh, bcoz u read `CosmosDBEndpointUri` in `CosmosDBStorage` and in your last previous comment you specify `AccountEndpoint` so thats why i said u to post your both of `json`

Comment: @ershoaib Ok. Actually `AccountEndpoint` is part of the full connection string which the emulator generates. It can be tested from https://cosmos.azure.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the Local Emulator for testing in Azure. Azure cannot find your `localhost` because it's outside of the boundaries of it's network.

It will search in it's own network and fail. You will need to point to an actual CosmosDB instance or somehow expose your emulator from a server or your pc to the Azure app service.

Keep in mind that the CosmosDB Emulator is only supposed to be used for Local development and nothing else. It is supposed to emulate behaviour and not be the real thing.

The recommended approach is to create a CosmosDB account and use that connection string.